# Print incremental numbers in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-dates

Cell `A1` holds a numerical value (e.g. `10`), and I'd like to output the list of numbers from 1 to that number in `B1`:

[image]

What's the formula I need for `B1`? It seems trivial, and I know it probably requires `ARRAYFORMULA` but I just don't know where to go from there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is as simple as using the following sequence formula

```
=SEQUENCE(A1)
```

[image: google sheets sequential/incremental numbers]

Or you even could have something like this:

```
=SEQUENCE(A2,1,A4,A6)
```

[image]

You could even use the `SEQUENCE` function for dates

```
=SEQUENCE(A2,1,A4,A6)
```

[image: creating an array of dates]

- [SEQUENCE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244?hl=en-GB)

Comment: I was hoping there was an easy way to do this :)

Comment: The `SEQUENCE` function is relatively new but really great. Glad it helped :)